# We are given $f: X \rightarrow P(X)$, $f(x) = X\backslash\{x\}$, and $X$ is a set. Is the function injective, surjective, bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am working on this problem in a beginners set theory class. I believe the function is injective but not surjective, thus is it not bijective.

We can show it is injective by letting $f(x) = f(x')$. Thus
\begin{align*}
X\backslash \{ x \} &= X\backslash \{ x' \} \\
X\backslash \left( X\backslash \{ x \} \right)&= X\backslash \left( X\backslash \{ x' \} \right) \\
x &= x'
\end{align*}

The surjective property does not hold since $x \in X$ is a single element. Thus $f(x) = X\backslash\{x\}$ only maps to the subsets of $P(X)$ of size $n-1$ where $n$ is the number of elements in $X$.

Since $f(x)$ is not surjective, it follows that it is not bijective.

Do others agree with my argument?

Comment: Your proof of injectivity is correct. As for surjectivity - $f$ cannot be surjective, this is a general argument called Cantor's Diagonal Method. Intuitively it is because $|X| < |P(X)|$.

Comment: Thanks, LinAlgMan. Is Cantor's Diagonal Method just another way to show surjectivity or is my argument for surjectivity actually incorrect?

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly here, but what happens if $X=\emptyset$? I'm pretty sure the empty function is vacuously a bijection.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow I don't think it would be surjective, because $P(\emptyset)$ has one element.

Comment: @Denis Indeed! Thank you for catching that.

Comment: This map never can be surjective because of Cantor's argument. Your argument is not correct when $X$ is an infinite set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your injectivity argument is correct.

As for surjectivity just note that nothing gets mapped to all of $X$.

Comment: Except if $X$ is a singleton ;)

Comment: Therefore, "Nothing is mapped to $X$" is more general

Comment: alright fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is right for injectivity.

For surjectivity, you assume that $X$ has finite size $n$, which is not necessary. You can try to  write the proof for any $X$, even the infinite ones.

This proof is a lot simpler that Cantor's diagonal mentioned in the comments, you don't need such a complicated tool here. Just exhibit a set that is not reached by $f.